# wanto install ubuntu on fresh hdd 500GB

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

i have a 500GB internal HDD- blank
want to install ubuntu + win 10 **dual boot**
downloaded the iso file *ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso* from ubuntu website
try to boot through USB- but says media not recognised.
same internal 500 HDD is recognised through an external cable.

can some one please guide.

Comment: How did you write the ISO to your thumb-drive?  My guess is you didn't write it correctly (it's not boot-able if it's just a file on the thumb-drive)  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview   
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview   
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview